# Laravel: Handle old url with get parameter

Tags: php, laravel-5

Before using Laravel I had a link like this:

```
/user.php?id=13
```

In Laravel I have rewritten the url to `/user/13`. However, I also want to maintain the old url for a couple of month. How can I retrieve it?

If I try

```
Route::get('/user.php', function(){
 dd("test"); 
});
```

then he cannot find the route, I guess because of the dot `.`, this is the result:

> No input file specified.

If I try

```
Route::get('/user', function(Request $request){
  dd( $request->input('id'));
});
```

then `/user?id=29` causes:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::input()

Although it is stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input)

> **Regardless of the HTTP verb**, the input method may be used to retrieve user input

So how can I get the route `user.php?id=13` and how to retrieve the input?

Comment: Add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your `web.php`

Comment: @kerbholz yes thanks that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make

```
Route::get('/user', function(Request $request){
  dd( $request->input('id'));
});
```

work you need to add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your web.php

Answer (score 1):

To retreive the GET input one needs to write:

```
Route::get('/user', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
  dd($request->input('id'));
});
```

Comment: Not quite true. You are not using any route *variables* in your route. `Route::get('/user/{id}')` does use a route variable. It's totally fine to use a route like `Route::get('/user.php')`

Comment: You could even do `Route::get('/user.py')` or `Route::get('/user.html')`

Comment: @kerbholz I just realized that `Route::get('/user.py')` or `Route::get('/user.html')`actually do work! But `Route::get('/user.php')` doesn't for some reason

Comment: I think that has to do with your Apache Rewrite rules. It should work if you stop Apache and use `php artisan serve` to use PHP's server

Comment: @kerbholz your right, please write an answer so I can check it.